# GDAL command for selecting only certain columns

Tags: gdal, fields-attributes

I am using the recent GDAL and QGIS versions.

In order for a study project, I need to develop a batchfile with several commands in it.

I have a shapefile with several columns which I dont need and which still are taking up lots of disk space.

In QGIS, I just deleted the columns which I dont need by "Drop Fields".

Unfortunately, theres no such option in GDAL as an command, neither an command, with whom I can choose to select only certain columns.

How should I be able to write a command for this certain problem then?

Maybe with a SQL command?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using shapefiles, you have vector layers. The vector "half" of GDAL is called OGR. The command `ogr2ogr` lets you convert vector layers, including selecting only a subset of attributes with the `-select` parameter.

The full documentation is at https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html. With additional parameters, you can also clip your layer and/or use a `-sql` `WHERE` clause, which may further decrease the size of the working dataset you need.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didnt think of that -select option! :)